# selecting the 1st element in a series of elements with class attribute

Tags: jquery

I am building a chrome extension and I need to be able to execute a `click()` on the first table with class `show_review`. The issue I have is that these links all have the same class with no ID.

Here is what I am trying to click there are multiple tables all with the same class:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="show_review" onmousemove="csmd1(this)" onmousedown="csmd2(this)" onclick="adOpen(this,1,317543,'680536')" msm="1" msc="1"></table>
```

Here is my code. It doesn't do anything when I reload. Just sits there no click has been made.

```
if ($(".show_review")[0].length){
    $(".show_review")[0].click();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure those element exist when you trigger the click event? Maybe you need to use the DOM ready event? see my update.

Comment: When you use the array accessors, you get the actual dom elements back out of the jQuery set, whereas `.eq(n)` gives you a jQuery set containing the element at position `n`. So: `$('.show_review')[0].length` is a bad, since you probably want to just test `$('.show_review').length` and then `$('.show_review')[0].click()` should be `$('.show_review').eq(0).click()`. Finally, since executing any function on an empty set is ok with jQuery, you don't even need the check in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($(".show_review").length){
    $(".show_review").eq(0).click();
}
```

Though you can do it with one line:

```
$(".show_review:first").click();
```

jQuery selectors and functions was designed to work with 0+ elements.
So in this case if no element was selected, the `click` function will just do nothing.

**Thanks you jQuery!**

---

**Update:**
You might need to use the DOM ready event.

```
$(function(){
    ...
    $(".show_review:first").click();        
    ...
});
```

Comment: so I tried `$(".show_review:first").click();` but same problem nothing happens. Could it be because it has onclick attribute?

Comment: @jon. **It's bad practice**, but no. show me the HTML, the problem is with the DOM or the selector.

Comment: @jon. Can you paste it in http://jsfiddle.net ? I'm having weird issues with pastebin.

Comment: @jon. That fiddle is bad. and missing the javascript part. Let's continue tomorrow, it's 01:23 in my time zone...

Comment: `$(".show_review:first").click()` indeed IS the answer to your question and it works just fine in your fiddle, it fails on `adOpen`, which is an entirely different thing. Also be aware that programatical clicking on banners is often against TOS of ad networks, so your problem could as well be the provider's precautions.

Comment: @jon. See Petr Vostrel last comment. accept the answer if the problem  you're asking about(how to trigger click on the 1st element) was solved. create a new question-thread if you have new issues. That question-thread is a mess with too much comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstTable = $("table.show_review:eq(0)");
```